# Change Name of Category Heading in New Post

Tags: admin

In the backend Admin pages I'd like to change the name of Heading for the Category selection box when a user is creating a new post.

Rather than this being titled "Categories" I'd like this to be called "Sectors."

[image]

Likewise I'd like to change "Tags" to "Technologies"

Thanks

Comment: theses taxonomies are used for default posts then I recommand you tu use a new custom type with new taxonomies : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `wp_taxonomies` object during `init` action. Then you can change the default labels for the **categories** and **posts tags**.

```
function wpse292282_rename_default_taxonomies() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;

    // Update datas for Category
    $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['category']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Sector';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Sector';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Sector';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Sector';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Sector';
    $labels->new_item = 'Sector';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Sector';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Sectors';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Sectors found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Sectors found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All Sectors';
    $labels->menu_name = 'Sector';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Sector';

       // Update datas for Tags
    $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'Technologies';
    $labels->singular_name = 'Technology';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add Technology';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Technology';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Technology';
    $labels->new_item = 'Technology';
    $labels->view_item = 'View Technology';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search Technologies';
    $labels->not_found = 'No Technologies found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Technologies found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All Technologies';
    $labels->menu_name = 'Technologies';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Technologies';

}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse292282_rename_default_taxonomies' );
```